# PHP Function and Variable inside echo Tag

Tags: php, echo, truncate

I have PHP code which fetches the articles from a database. The fetching works fine and i get the list of the articles

I needed to truncate the contents of each article so it fits inside the space. But i couldnt figure out a way to write. Below is the necessary code which needs to be corrected.. For better understanding i have included only the necessary parts inside while loop.

```
while( ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)))
                    {
                    echo"   <article id='post-31' class='post-31 post type-post status-publish format-aside hentry category-news blogitem'>
                            <div class='blogitem-container'>
                                <div class='meta-container'>
                                    <div class='rb_blog_meta_date_wrapper'>
                                        <div class='rb_blog_meta_date rb_format_aside'><span class='rb_blog_meta_date_day'>02</span> JAN</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='rb_meta_links '>
                                        <h3><a href='video-postformat.html'>".$row['title']."</a></h3>
                                        <hr>
                                        &nbsp;<i class='fa fa-folder'></i> <a href='#' title='View all posts in News' rel='category tag'>".$row['category']."</a>  &nbsp;<i class='fa fa-heart bloglike '></i> <a class='bloglikelink' href='#' data-post-id='31'>".$row['like']."</a>                              
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- .rb_meta_links -->
                                    <div class='clearfix'></div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- .meta-container -->
                                <div class='blogtext' >
                                    <p align='justify'>'".mb_strimwidth('.$row['content'].', 0, 100, '...')."'
</p>
                                </div>
                                <!-- .blogtext -->
                                <a class='blogreadmore' href='video-postformat.html' >Read More</a>
                                <div class='clearfix'></div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- .blogitem-container -->
                        </article>";
                    }
                        ?>
```

Can somebody rewrite the echo tag so it works. I am a Beginner Programmer. 
Edited the Question. Included the whole code.

```
<p align='justify'>'".mb_strimwidth('.$row['content'].', 0, 100, '...')."'
</p>.
```

Need this piece of code corrected

Original question, so as not to confuse others looking at answers:

```
while( ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))){
    echo "mb_strimwidth("'.$row['content'].'", 0, 10, "...");"; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using way too many quotes where you shouldn't at all

```
echo mb_strimwidth($row['content'], 0, 10, "...");
```

Here

```
<p align='justify'>'".mb_strimwidth($row['content'], 0, 100, '...')."'
```

Comment: It's not that difficult, same answer basically still applies. But I'll fix it for you again...

Answer (score 1):

Seems some problem in your echo. `"` is not necessary.

```
echo mb_strimwidth($row['content'], 0, 10, "...");
```